# Variable number of arguments in function

Tags: python, function, arguments, multiple-arguments

Is it possible to run a function like this:

```
def call(a,*alphabets,*numbers):
    print(a)
    print(alphabets)
    print(numbers)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-331-ddaef8a7e66f>", line 1
    def call(a,*alphabets,*numbers):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can somebody tell me if there's an alternative way to do this?

Comment: No, the `*` is greedy, it will consume all remaining (positional) arguments. In any case, how could Python know how to split them between the two different variables?

Comment: True, I'm not sure how. I have an assignment which needs me to do something like this. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: hi @Omar, I need atleast 2 variable number of arguments to be passed in a function.

Comment: Why would you need smth like that? "*2 variable number of argument*" makes no sense because the 2nd variable arument number would be automatically invalidated by the 1st. If you can't make it using `*args, **kwargs`, then either the design is poor, or *Python* is not the appropriate language for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply: require the caller to pass two lists (or tuples or whatever):

```
def call(a,alphabets=None,numbers=None):
    if alphabets is None:
        alphabets = []
    if numbers is None:
        numbers = []
    print(a)
    print(alphabets)
    print(numbers)


call("?")
call("?", ["a", "b", "c"])
call("?", ["a", "b", "c"], (1, 2, 3))
call("?"), None, (1, 2, 3))
# etc
```

Comment: If the caller can pass a tuple, why not `def call(a,alphabets=(),numbers=()): print(a); ....`?

Comment: @VPfB mostly because I'm dumb actually <g>